# Why pandas read_csv returns only the first 1024 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

We're using pandas on jupyter notebook to load a csv file like:

```
 import pandas as pd
 dat=pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

running the above line of code more than once returns only the first 1024 columns. We've tried options like:

```
pd.read_csv("data.csv", na_values ='na', engine='python', delimiter=',', header=0, quoting=csv.QUOTE) to no avail.
```

Here's a snapshot of the data:

[image]

What is the right way to read a csv file as a pandas dataframe ?

Comment: impossible to answer without your actual csv in order to reproduce

Comment: I don't think read_csv restrict you to read a csv file which header length has more than 1024. I checked this below code for you, `df=pd.DataFrame(index=range(1),columns=range(1200))
df.to_csv('s14.csv')
df=pd.read_csv('s14.csv')
print df`

But works as I exptected.

Comment: `read_csv` is the right way to read a csv file as a pandas dataframe. Are you getting all the columns? Or displays only 1024 columns? give some more details to your question

Comment: I've found in the past that excell limits documents to a certain number of columns, maybe this is the cause of your problem?

Comment: @Pallie my data is stored in csv format in librecalc, actually it does seem that librecalc max.number of columns to 1024.thanks for this info.i tried using read_excel but the problem remains.

Comment: @EdChum yes, updated with data snapshot

Comment: @MohamedThasinah dat.shape shows the right number of rows but only 1024 columns.So I think only 1024 cols are fetched.

Comment: @svk - I think your file parsed only to get only 1024 columns, there  must be a problem with the file, one typical problem will be unexpected break of seperator. please take a deep look at your input file.

Answer (score 1):

Check the csv file you are using. I have just tested read_csv for 1,804 columns and it does work.

see the mockup below:

```
import pandas as pd
dat=pd.read_csv("bigcolumns.csv")
dat
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: i have added the data snapshot.it's actually stored in librecalc as a .csv file.

Comment: it really doesnt help much. I am not sure how you can save say 10 lines of the csv file somewhere for others to play with. But that could be the way to go. Actually, you can try it too. Save 10 lines with all the columns and see if it works.

Comment: it is the same problem even with fewer columns.i suspect it is because of clrf/lf.is there a way to standardize a csv file this way?